# Trying to set the location of an image within an image

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to move the yellow dot images to their respective location. I have a handful of coordinates and the map itself but am unsure of how to put the two together.  Here's some code that show's what I am doing:

```
<v-img
    :src="zone.image"
    alt=""
>
    <v-layout pa-2 column fill-height class="lightbox white--text">
        <v-flex shrink>
            <div v-for="(mob, index) in mobs" :key="index">
            {{ mob.coordinates }}
                <v-img
                    src="https://classicdb.ch/templates/wowhead/images/map-pin-yellow.png"
                    alt=""
                    height="11px"
                    width="11px"
                >
                </v-img>
            </div>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</v-img>
```

Here's what this creates: [image: Image of map with images inside and hopeful coordinate placement]

Comment: Absolute positioning based on your co-ordinate system - something like - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Comment: if you're working with web mapping try to use vuelayers is a powerful library